# Should I make query call for for each item even when I have the full Flow of list?

Tags: android-room, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I'm recently trying to learn MVVM with jetpack compose.
Currently, I'm looking at:

https://github.com/stevdza-san/To-Do-Compose/blob/Part-13-Course_Updates/app/src/main/java/com/example/to_docompose/data/repositories/ToDoRepository.kt

The part I'm interested in:

```kotlin
class ToDoRepository @Inject constructor(private val toDoDao: ToDoDao) {

    val getAllTasks: Flow<List<ToDoTask>> = toDoDao.getAllTasks()

    fun getSelectedTask(taskId: Int): Flow<ToDoTask> {
        return toDoDao.getSelectedTask(taskId = taskId)
    }
}
```

You see the dev is making another query call to get the selected task, whose Id was obtained from *alltasks* query call. Should it not be wise (less resource extensive) to get the task from the already obtained list?

I know that Flow does not currently hold that whole list but is it not possible to get the selected task from Flow, or is it even worth it (i.e make new calls for each task even when I got the Task id from MutableStateFlow which itself got it from the *alltask* flow, is more beneficial)?

Update/Note: My use case is different from the given source. I.e. I'll keep observing the whole list Flow, but don't require the single item to be Flow (observable). So, if you find such code please attach them here (the function to get the item should be **in the repository** not in ViewModel).

Comment: Could you show please the code where "the dev is making another query call to get the selected task, whose Id was obtained from alltasks query call"?

Comment: @Sergio "getSelectedTask" calls @Query("SELECT * FROM todo_table WHERE id=:taskId")
    fun getSelectedTask(taskId: Int): Flow<ToDoTask>

link here https://github.com/stevdza-san/To-Do-Compose/blob/Part-13-Course_Updates/app/src/main/java/com/example/to_docompose/data/ToDoDao.kt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on the same screen still and still need to be observing the full list, then yes mapping that flow to just pull out the single todo is maybe slightly more efficient? Although the tradeoff in extra code complexity might not be worth the minimal gain it may cause. It might not even be faster if you have a large list and your filter has to search through the whole list to find the one with the correct ID on every change to that list.

Often though if you are changing screens in your app for example to go to the detail screen, it is more efficient to stop observing the full list of changes and then start observing just the single item. In that case you would do as you describe and create a new Flow just with the selected item on your new screen.

Comment: Even if it's complex code, I'm open to possibilities. As my use case is different. I.e. I'll keep observing the whole list Flow, but don't require the single item to be Flow (observable). So, if you find such code please attach them here (the function to get the item should be in the repository not in ViewModel), that'll be very kind of you.